# how to get spark-sbumit logging result

Tags: apache-spark, jar, spark-submit

When i submit spark job too terminal, it's has logging result like image in terminal.

How can i get it and set it to value or object?[image: spark-submit result]

Comment: Please paste your logs as plain text in a code block, not as an image.

Comment: And also please clarify your question, even looking at your image, I'm really not sure what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You can pipe spark-submit command to the log file like this:

```
spark-submit ... > log.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

You can see logs from application and you can always write logs to .text files

```
yarn logs -applicationId <application ID> [OPTIONS]
```

Application ID can be found through cluster UI